# ClipToBounds property in WinRT

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime

I'm trying to find the equivalent of [ClipToBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) in Windows Runtime.
If it doesn't exists is there a way to recreate this behavior ?

Comment: Here is a great article about it `https://www.domysee.com/blogposts/canvas-rendering-out-of-bounds`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution I use :

```
public class Clip
{
    public static bool GetToBounds(DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        return (bool)depObj.GetValue(ToBoundsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetToBounds(DependencyObject depObj, bool clipToBounds)
    {
        depObj.SetValue(ToBoundsProperty, clipToBounds);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the ToBounds Dependency Property.
    /// <summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToBoundsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ToBounds", typeof(bool),
        typeof(Clip), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnToBoundsPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnToBoundsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null)
        {
            ClipToBounds(fe);

            // whenever the element which this property is attached to is loaded
            // or re-sizes, we need to update its clipping geometry
            fe.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(fe_Loaded);
            fe.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(fe_SizeChanged);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a rectangular clipping geometry which matches the geometry of the
    /// passed element
    /// </summary>
    private static void ClipToBounds(FrameworkElement fe)
    {
        if (GetToBounds(fe))
        {
            fe.Clip = new RectangleGeometry()
            {
                Rect = new Rect(0, 0, fe.ActualWidth, fe.ActualHeight)
            };
        }
        else
        {
            fe.Clip = null;
        }
    }

    static void fe_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClipToBounds(sender as FrameworkElement);
    }

    static void fe_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClipToBounds(sender as FrameworkElement);
    }
}
```

Found it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/0e80a0ed-bf4d-479f-bbf1-9fefc1db0857)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the 'Clip' property here is some xaml

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="50">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 0 100 50"/>
    </Grid.Clip>
</Grid>
```

The parameter of the 'Rect' property are: Rect="x y width height"

Hope it helps

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

This is implemented in WinRTXamlToolkit (https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) which is also available as Nuget package.

Add to XAML header:

```
xmlns:extensions="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions"
```

Then, for example in XAML Canvas component

```
<Canvas extensions:FrameworkElementExtensions.ClipToBounds="True"/>
```