# c# uwp cut of usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls, uwp, overlap

I have created a usercontrol that has some controls outside of view, but they will be visible as soon as animation show them. Animation is changing their offset, so they slowly appears. Now, when I put my usercontrol on some view,
those controls that I don't want to be seen are visible. I tied to use Grid, GridView, Canvas...but everytime I can see these controls.

I need 4 of my usercontrols in a row, to be resizeble. And this issue makes some usercontrols to overlap eachother.

Here is how I have show them in grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridDown" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myControl1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Column="0"/>
        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myControl2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Column="1"/>
        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myControl3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Column="2"/>
        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myControl4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Column="3"/>

</Grid>
```

How to show only central part of my usercontrol? How to hide rest of the controls that I don't want to be seen? What control is the best for this?

Comment: How did you achieve your UserControl? Please share a [mcve] with us.

Answer (score 1):

To control what's displayed you need to tell it where to set the limits of what to show. In WPF has the helpful [ClipToBounds property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) but unfortunately this isn't available in UWP so you need to set the 'Clip' property yourself.

So, if your page looked like this

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <local:MyControl/>
    <local:MyControl/>
    <local:MyControl/>
</StackPanel>
```

And your control XAML looked like this

```
<Grid Height="50" Width="100">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 0 100 50"/>
    </Grid.Clip>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowRedBit">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Rectangle.RenderTransform.(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="RedBit"
                             Duration="0:0:2"
                     To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click">show red</Button>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="50" Width="50" x:Name="RedBit" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-100"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

You can see that I've manually set the clip property to be the same as the size of the control.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13668236/1755) also show some other approaches, including a way to set it dynamically.