# WPF - Draw curved line from center screen to margin that dynamically adapts as the screen changes

Tags: wpf, mvvm, draw

I want to draw a curved line from the center of the screen to the top left margin. As the window resizes the line should change it's coordinates.
Is it possible to do this respecting MVVM ?
Example:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a Viewbox scales the rendered output of its content (including e.g. the `StrokeThickness` of a `Path`), but not the geometry of a drawing.

The following approach works without scaling the `StrokeThickness`, because the `Ellipse` control scales its geometry to fit its bounds:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border ClipToBounds="True">
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0,1">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have observed the scaling of the stroke thickness. In a WPF application this solution works, unfortunately when using the same code in a UWP project Border does not have the property ClipToBounds witch I have seen is essential to mimic a line and not half an ellipse.

Comment: You have tagged your question with WPF only. Anyway, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13668236/1136211

Comment: my mistake, have marked this as a more optimal answer

Answer (score 1):

Create a grid in your window with 2 columns both with a width of 1*

To your grid in the first column add a viewbox with StretchDirection = Both and Stretch = Fill

Within the viewbox add your curve.

As the window resizes the columns will get smaller and the viewbox will stetch the contents down.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>   
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">
        <Canvas Width="100" Height="200">
            <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathGeometry.Figures>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0" IsClosed="False">
                                <ArcSegment Point="100,100" Size="100 100"/>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```